# Как в Bootstrap 3 отключить изменение порядка следования адаптивных блоков

Tags: html, css, css3, bootstrap

Есть стандартный файл стилей bootstrap.min.css. Никак не пойму как сделать так, чтобы на устройствах с разрешением до 600px слои не смещались.
Понимаю, что это связано с col-xs-push, или push-md но в Bootstrap вообще ничего не понимаю.
Помогите пожалуйста.